# The issue about a braced-init-list that is used as a non-type template argument

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
template<int I>
struct Test{};
int main(){
  Test<{0}> t;
}
```

Consider the above code, GCC and Clang all complain such a code is ill-formed. However, I don't know why?

According to the rule for something that is eligible to be a non-type argument:
[temp.arg.nontype#2](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2)

> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a converted constant expression ([expr.const]) of the type of the template-parameter.

The rule hints the converted expression shall be a converted constant expression, the concept is defined here.

[expr.const#10](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#10)

> A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, **implicitly converted to type T**, where the converted expression is a constant expression and the implicit conversion sequence contains only:
>
> > [list ommited]

> An expression E can be implicitly converted to a type T if and only if the declaration T t=E; is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable t.

This sentence seems to say, for an **expression E**, only it shall satisfy some conditions may it be converted to an expression of the destination type. It does not indicate that it prohibits braced-init-list as a target that will be implicitly converted. In other words, the invented declaration `int t = {0};` is absolutely well-formed.

Moreover, the rule in [over.ics.list#10](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.list#10) says:

> if the initializer list has one element that is not itself an initializer list, the implicit conversion sequence is the one required to convert the element to the parameter type.

That means the implicit conversion sequences that from `{0}` to type `int` is equivalent to from `0` to `int`, which is a standard conversion which is permitted in the `[list ommited]`.

So, why a braced-init-list can not be used as a non-type template argument? which rule in the standard prohibits this usage? In other words, which rule prohibits that the implicit conversions cannot be applied to a braced-init-list(Presumably, the question should be which something can be implicit converted)?

Comment: You are overly focused on whether `{0}` is a converted constant expression or not that you're forgetting that it isn't an expression in the first place. Try compiling `{0};`. Your argument falls apart because it states "for **expression E**".

Comment: It's not that the standard prohibits it explicitly, it just doesn't allow it. There's a list of things that can be used as a template argument, and `{...}` is not one of them.

Comment: @orlp The rule didn't say the non-type template argument shall be an expression

Comment: @orlp Yes, it states for **an expression**, but it definitely says that it prohibits a braced-init-list.

Comment: @cigien where is the rule prohibits that?

Comment: Please spend a few minutes reading the target first. The answers there address your questions.

Comment: @jackX: Your quote from the standard says "shall be a converted constant expression". And [expr.const] says that a constant expressions are expressions. Or rather, only an expression can be a constant expression, but same difference.

Comment: @NicolBolas  That only says the **result** should be a constant expression, it does not hint the origin that be converted to a constant expression must be an expression.

Comment: @jackX: How else can you read "A converted constant expression of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T" as anything other than a construct that starts with an *expression*?

Comment: @NicolBolas  such as `constexpr int v = {0};`, Isn't `v` not a constant expression? Is `{0}` an expression?

Comment: @cigien Oh, thanks. I see.  The argument must be permitted by the grammar for template-argument. `braced-init-list` is not a valid grammar of the template-argument.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.